# Javascript moving child when dragging on parent

Tags: javascript

I want to move child element when dragging on parent and the element itself, and the parent shouldn't be moved.
here is my [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aH63X6Ngyuk9XJRfwMNf?p=preview)
As in the demo, I want to move the red box when either drag on it or drag on its parent (the background), but I couldn't compute the right position, could you help me?
Other question is why I can't `off`the `mousemove event` when I set `.off('mousemove', mousemove')`
Thank you very much

Comment: Why not use jquery draggable? https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: in fact I only need this feature, so I don't want to import a whole jquery library to my project

Comment: You don't need whole library, you can download only specific features: https://jqueryui.com/download/#!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some changes. This works ;)

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Tomasito665/42bs9k5k/1/)

```
$(function(){
  var graph = $('.graph')[0];
  var parent = $(graph).parent();

  var lockX = 0;
  var lockY = 0;

  var mousemove = function(e){
        $(graph).offset({
            top: e.pageY + lockY,
            left: e.pageX + lockX
        });
    };

  parent.on('mousedown', function(e) {
        lockY = $(graph).offset().top - e.pageY;
        lockX = $(graph).offset().left - e.pageX;

        $(this).addClass('draggable')
          .on('mousemove', mousemove)
          .on('mouseup', function(){
            $(this).off('mousemove', mousemove)
        })

        event.preventDefault()
    });

    $('.graph').parent().on('mouseup', function(e) {
        $('.draggable')
            .off('mousemove', mousemove)
            .removeClass('draggable');
    });
});
```

#### **EDIT**

The only actual change I made to make it work was:

```
.offset({
    // instead of: e.pageY - $('.draggable').outerHeight() / 2 + dtop
    top: e.pageY + dtop,

    // instead of: e.pageX - $('.draggable').outerWidth() / 2 + dleft
    left: e.pageX + dleft
})
```

PS: In the example in the JS Fiddle I changed `dleft` and `dtop` respectively to `lockX` and `lockY`. Ofcourse, that is a pure semantical thing.